# multiple devise auth for WEB and API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

### Problem Statement

I'm Newbie in Rails and following [this tutorial](https://github.com/DakotaLMartinez/rails-devise-jwt-tutorial) for setting up JWT based authentication in API, and working on an existing web application that uses Devise. My task at the moment is to add a JSON API to the application.

This rails project works fine for a web applications. However, Incase of API I'm getting empty `resource` while I still have value in `params`.

---

### Environment

`rails` (6.1.4)

`devise` (4.8.0)
`devise-jwt` (0.9.0)

`warden` (1.2.9)
`warden-jwt_auth` (0.6.0)

---

### Controller & Route

`app/controllers/api/v1/users/registrations_controller.rb`

```
class Api::V1::Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    respond_to :json
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  
    # POST /resource
    def create
      super
    end
  
    private
    def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})
    if resource.persisted?
        render json: {
        status: { code: 200, message: "Signed up sucessfully." },
        data: UserSerializer.new(resource).serializable_hash[:data][:attributes]
        }
    else
        render json: {
        status: { message: "User couldn't be created successfully. #{resource.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}" }
        }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
    end
end
```

`config/routes.rb`

```
# For Web 
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
# Authentication  
devise_scope :user do
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new", as: :login
    get "/logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :logout
    get "/signup" => "registrations#new", :as => :signup
    scope "my" do
      get "profile", to: "registrations#edit"
      put "profile/update", to: "registrations#update"
    end
end

authenticated :user do
    resources :dashboard, only: [:index] do
      collection do
        get :home
      end
    end
end

unauthenticated do
    as :user do
      root to: "devise/sessions#new", as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
end

# For API 
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do

      devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: {
        sign_in: 'login',
        sign_out: 'logout',
        registration: 'signup'
      },
      controllers: {
        sessions: 'api/v1/users/sessions',
        registrations: 'api/v1/users/registrations'
      }
    end
end
```

---

### Debugging information

`app/controllers/api/v1/users/registrations_controller.rb`

```
|    66:   private
|    67:     def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})
|    68:       byebug
| => 69:       if resource.persisted?
|    70:         render json: {
|    71:           status: { code: 200, message: "Signed up sucessfully." },
|    72:           data: UserSerializer.new(resource).serializable_hash[:data][:attributes]
|    73:         }
| (byebug) resource
| #<User 
    id: nil, 
    email: "", 
    first_name: "", 
    last_name: "", 
    role: "member", 
    created_at: nil, 
    updated_at: nil, 
    jti: nil
>

| (byebug) params
| #<ActionController::Parameters 
    {
        "email"=>"test@test.com", 
        "first_name"=>"John", 
        "last_name"=>"Wick", 
        "password"=>"password", 
        "controller"=>"api/v1/users/registrations", 
        "action"=>"create", 
        "registration"=>{
            "email"=>"test@test.com", 
            "first_name"=>"John", 
            "last_name"=>"Wick", 
            "password"=>"password"
        }
    } permitted: false>
```

---

- Request

```
curl -X POST \
http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/signup \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Wick",
    "password": "password"
}'
```

- Response

```
{
    "status": {
        "message": "User couldn't be created successfully. Email can't be blank and Password can't be blank"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution as you're now returning the same response for all the actions of the controller. `status: { code: 200, message: "Signed up sucessfully." }` is also a huge anti-pattern. Return actual HTTP status codes **as a header**.

Comment: @max, Thanks, I've added my API request and response in question at the bottom. Please refer the same.

Comment: @max, As you can see that the above request is returning `"status": {
        "message": "User couldn't be created successfully. Email can't be blank and Password can't be blank"
    }` even though i'm sending the `email` and `password` in request.

Comment: You need to pass the params nested in the key `user`. Rails by default is wrapping the parameters in `registrations` based off the controller name by devise actually expects them to be wrapped in the same key that you used for `devise_for`.

Comment: I would really write an integration test / request spec here instead of using cURL as the time spent writing the correct call could actually be used to safeguard agains future regressions.

Comment: @max, I'm getting the `params` in the `registrations_controller.rb` but getting empty `resource`. You can check the same in **Debugging information** section of above question.

Comment: You are not nesting the params inside the user key as suggested by max